# Why I get "ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG" on chrome?

Tags: php, google-chrome

The following code is executed correctly on firefox, but not on Chrome. The later always displays "ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG". This error occurs when I iterate through a folder containing more than 10000 items (files) - it must be long task.

Please can anyone explain me how to avoid this error? The error disappears if I "echo"-ing something just after ob_end_clean();

```
<?php

ini_set('max_execution_time', 600);

function FileItemsCount($it, &$count_ref)
{ 
   foreach ($it as $file)
   {
        $count_ref += 1;

ob_start();
        session_start();
        $_SESSION['progress'] = $count_ref;
        session_write_close(); 
ob_end_clean() ;

        $is_folder = $it->hasChildren();
        if ($is_folder)
        {
           FileItemsCount($it->getChildren(), $count_ref);
        }
    }
}

$dir = "C:/Users/sstefanov/xampp";

$it = new RecursiveDirectoryIterator($dir, RecursiveDirectoryIterator::SKIP_DOTS);

$count = 0;
FileItemsCount($it, $count);


echo $count;

?>
```

Comment: I'd suspect that's because you open and close the session in your loop every time (why are you doing that anyway?) - that might(?) result in session_start generating a new SetCookie header each time, and therefor Chrome get's pissed ...

Comment: CBroe is correct, there are size limits to the number of headers a browser will accept. That also implies a limit to the number of cookies you can create.

Comment: I'm C++ programmer and I think of session_start()/session_write_close() as Enter/Leave critical_section in order to synchronize $_SESSION['progress'] variable between parallel php processes. May be I'm wrong but cannot find other way of synchromization in php.

Answer (score 17):

Some necroposting for those, who will search an answer :)

I tried to do the similar thing - to unblock parallel ajax requests, one of which called for long operation and other for checking progress.
I also started the session each time to write new value and stopped it right after. And I also got `ERR_RESPONSE_HEADERS_TOO_BIG` error in Chrome.

The reason was that PHP sent `Set-Cookie` header with each session start in my case. And when long ajax request was finishing, server sent all `Set-Cookie` headers to the browser.

To fix this I removed the `Set-Cookie` headers by calling 
`header_remove('Set-Cookie');` before the output.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the case in this questions, but I thought that it would be useful to share that this error could also arise if too much data is being printed/echoed by the server (e.g. for debugging purposes)

Comment: Thank you! I was getting this with the ChromePhp logger sending back 300KB of debug information.